# ABI Split failed in NativeScript 2.3.0

Tags: android, nativescript, glade

I’ve asked for help in the general group but most people didnt get it work as well.
Im having a huge problem ridiculous apk size of my simple app. I used @markosko nativescript filter to reduce the app to 14MB from 17.2MB, even `nativescript-snapshot` couldn't help still 17MB for release version.

I tried using the ABI split sample in the nativescipt documentation but what I noticed is that it’s trying to split but the glade is using same name for all the apks so I came up with this in my app.glade

```glade
def tnsBuildMultipleApks=true;

android {  
    defaultConfig {  
        generatedDensities = []
        applicationId = "com.maliyo.oneclick"  
        versionCode Integer.parseInt("" + "1" + "0")
    }  
    aaptOptions {  
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
    }
    if (Boolean.valueOf(tnsBuildMultipleApks)) {
        splits {
            abi {
                enable true
                reset()
                include  'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'mips'
                universalApk true
            }
        }
    }
} 

def getDate() {
  def date = new Date()
  def formattedDate = date.format('yyyyMMdd')
  return formattedDate
}

// map for the version code that gives each ABI a value
ext.versionCodes = [
    'F0F1F2X86Debug':1, 'F0F1F2ArmeabiDebug':2, 'F0F1F2Armeabi-v7aDebug':3, 'F0F1F2MipsDebug':4,
    'F0F1F2X86Release':1, 'F0F1F2ArmeabiRelease':2, 'F0F1F2Armeabi-v7aRelease':3, 'F0F1F2MipsRelease':4
    ]

// For each APK output variant, override versionCode with a combination of
// ABI APK value * 100 + defaultConfig.versionCode
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    // assign different version code for each output
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        if (output.outputFile != null && output.outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
            println("******************************************************")
            println(output);
            println(output.getVariantOutputData().getFullName())

            if (Boolean.valueOf(tnsBuildMultipleApks)) {
                def file = output.outputFile
                // version at the end of each built apk
                //output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + android.defaultConfig.versionName + "-" + getDate() + ".apk"))
                output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + output.getVariantOutputData().getFullName() + "-" + getDate() + ".apk"))
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                    //(assd++) * 100
                    project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getVariantOutputData().getFullName(), 0) * 100
                    + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}
/**/
```

Fine, it splits but I think because I hacked the filename at output the adb couldn't find one to push the apk to the device or emulator due to the naming pattern, maybe, just saying `apk not found`.

I tried to manually send the appropriate apk to the device via USB, it app installed successfully but it crashes after splashscreen saying    `metadata/treeNodeStream.dat could not be loaded`

## UPDATE

@plamen-petkov thanks so much for your contribution, I agree with you that it work fine, when you build one after another changing the abi filter. But with this in my app.gradle, I managed to build multiple apks successfully and tested and OK.

but is like the the tns is only pushing `appname-debug.apk` or `appname-release.apk` to the adb. I can toggle this splitting off with `tnsBuildMultipleApks` and maybe when Im still testing I can turn it off and use `tns run android` and when I want to make final build and it turn it one again as it works fine with `tns build android --release ....`

```
// Add your native dependencies here:

// Uncomment to add recyclerview-v7 dependency
//dependencies {
//  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
//}
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper //used to parse package.json

def tnsBuildMultipleApks=true;
String content = new File("$projectDir/../../app/package.json").getText("UTF-8")
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def appPackageJson = jsonSlurper.parseText(content)

android {  
    defaultConfig {  
        generatedDensities = []
        applicationId = appPackageJson.nativescript.id  
        versionCode = appPackageJson.version_code ?: 1
    }

    aaptOptions {  
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
    }
    if (Boolean.valueOf(tnsBuildMultipleApks)) {
        splits {
            abi {
                enable true
                reset()
                include  'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
                universalApk true
            }
        }
    }
}

// map for the version code that gives each ABI a value
ext.versionCodes = [
    'x86':1, 'armeabi-v7a':2, 'arm64-v8a':3
]

// For each APK output variant, override versionCode with a combination of
// ABI APK value * 100 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
// getAbiFilter() not working for me so I extracted it from getFullname()
if (Boolean.valueOf(tnsBuildMultipleApks)) {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        println(appPackageJson)
        println(android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
        println(android.defaultConfig.applicationId)

        def name
        def flavorNamesConcat = ""

        variant.productFlavors.each() { flavor ->
            flavorNamesConcat += flavor.name
        }
        flavorNamesConcat = flavorNamesConcat.toLowerCase()
        println(flavorNamesConcat)

        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            if (output.outputFile != null && output.outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
                //You may look for this path in your console to see what the values are
                println("******************************************************")
                println(output); println(output.getVariantOutputData().getFullName())

                def abiName = output.getVariantOutputData().getFullName().toLowerCase().replace(flavorNamesConcat, "").replace(project.ext.selectedBuildType, "")
                println(abiName)


                def file = output.outputFile
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                    project.ext.versionCodes.get(abiName, 0) * 100
                    + android.defaultConfig.versionCode

                def apkDirectory = output.packageApplication.outputFile.parentFile
                def apkNamePrefix = output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-" + abiName)

                if (output.zipAlign) {
                    name = apkNamePrefix + ".apk"
                    output.outputFile = new File(apkDirectory, name);
                }

                name = apkNamePrefix + "-unaligned.apk"
                output.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(apkDirectory, name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work so well for me now, both generating apks and `tns run android` runs fine now, thanks.

```
    // Add your native dependencies here:

// Uncomment to add recyclerview-v7 dependency
//dependencies {
//  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
//}
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper //used to parse package.json

def tnsBuildMultipleApks=true;
String content = new File("$projectDir/../../app/package.json").getText("UTF-8")
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def appPackageJson = jsonSlurper.parseText(content)

android {  
    defaultConfig {  
        generatedDensities = []
        applicationId = appPackageJson.nativescript.id  
        versionCode = appPackageJson.version_code ?: 1
    }

    aaptOptions {  
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
    }
    if (Boolean.valueOf(tnsBuildMultipleApks)) {
        splits {
            abi {
                enable true
                reset()
                include  'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
                universalApk true
            }
        }
    }
}

// map for the version code that gives each ABI a value
ext.versionCodes = [
    'x86':1, 'armeabi-v7a':2, 'arm64-v8a':3
]

// For each APK output variant, override versionCode with a combination of
// ABI APK value * 100 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
// getAbiFilter() not working for me so I extracted it from getFullname()
if (Boolean.valueOf(tnsBuildMultipleApks)) {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        println(appPackageJson)
        println(android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
        println(android.defaultConfig.applicationId)

        def name
        def flavorNamesConcat = ""

        variant.productFlavors.each() { flavor ->
            flavorNamesConcat += flavor.name
        }
        flavorNamesConcat = flavorNamesConcat.toLowerCase()
        println(flavorNamesConcat)

        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            if (output.outputFile != null && output.outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
                //You may look for this path in your console to see what the values are
                println("******************************************************")
                println(output); println(output.getVariantOutputData().getFullName())

                def abiName = output.getVariantOutputData().getFullName().toLowerCase().replace(flavorNamesConcat, "").replace(project.ext.selectedBuildType, "")
                println(abiName)


                def file = output.outputFile
                def versionCode = project.ext.versionCodes.get(abiName, 0);
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                    project.ext.versionCodes.get(abiName, 0) * 100
                    + android.defaultConfig.versionCode

                def apkDirectory = output.packageApplication.outputFile.parentFile
                println(output.outputFile.name)
                def apkNamePrefix = ""
                if(versionCode){
                    apkNamePrefix = output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-" + abiName)
                }
                else {
                    apkNamePrefix = output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "")
                }

                if (output.zipAlign) {
                    name = apkNamePrefix + ".apk"
                    output.outputFile = new File(apkDirectory, name);
                }

                name = apkNamePrefix + "-unaligned.apk"
                output.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(apkDirectory, name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

ABI splits can be useful if you use them one at a time. Here's an example:

```
android {  
...
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include  'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }
...
}
```

The resulting .apk file will only contain the libraries necessary for armeabi-v7a devices, because it's the only architecture mentioned in the ABI splits configuration above. The ABIs available are 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86' as pointed out in the [documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/publishing/publishing-android-apps#apks-with-abi-splits), so you can't use 'armeabi' or 'mips' architectures.

Furthermore you don't need this line: 'universalApk true', because what it does is ignoring the splits and making one .apk file containing all the provided architectures and you want the opposite.

You can also follow the progress of [this](https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/issues/529) issue as it will decrease the .apk size even more.

Hope this helps!